# Replace malloc and free by new and delete in a memory pool

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I am using a templated memory pool that uses the following union to store the data:

```
union MemoryPoolNode
{
    MemoryPoolNode *next;
    T data;
};
```

Previously, I was allocating memory for a new node using malloc:

```
MemoryPoolNode *node = (MemoryPoolNode*)malloc(sizeof(MemoryPoolNode));
```

And to free it:

```
free(node);
```

Now, I want to replace my calls to malloc and free by new and delete.

For this purpose, to allocate memory for a node, I'm now doing:

```
MemoryPoolNode *node = (MemoryPoolNode*)new char[sizeof(MemoryPoolNode)];
```

And to free it:

```
char *toDelete = (char*)node;
delete[] toDelete;
```

Is it the right way to do it?

The type T in my union can be a class with a constructor and a destructor and I don't want the constructor nor the destructor to be called when I allocate memory for new node in my memory pool because I already use the placement new and I call the destructor manually each time a node is popped and put back in the memory pool, so I just want to allocate and free memory, just like malloc and free would do.

FYI, I'm replacing malloc and free because the pool is used in an environment where "new" and "delete" can have been overridden to allocate memory accordingly (user space, kernel, ...).

Comment: Why are you trying to replace malloc and free with new and delete? If you aren't trying to allocate a new, valid object, why call `new`?

Comment: Everything works perfectly with malloc and free. The only reason why I'm replacing them is because the memory pool works in an environment where  "new" can have been overridden to allocate memory differently (user space / kernel / ...)

Comment: Well, then your method won't work since it won't use a customized `operator new`. Arrays don't use `operator new`. And if `operator new[]` has been overriden, you'll get the customizations desired for arrays even though your union is not an array.

Comment: Both of them are overridden, actually.

Comment: Constructing a `MemoryPoolNode` won't construct a `T`. How could it? What if it was a union of a `T` and a `std::string` -- how would it know which to construct?

Comment: No, this is indeed the behaviour I expect. Actually, I just want the allocation to allocate the memory, without anything else. It is my job when someone requests a node from the memory pool to call the constructor manually via the placement new and to call the destructor when the node is put back into the pool. This is why it was working with "malloc" and "free". But now, I want to use "new[]" and "delete" to benefit from the fact that they are overridden and allocate memory in the right way, depending on the fact that we are in user space or in the kernel.

Comment: How does your code currently construct a valid `MemoryPoolNode`? It seems you've painted yourself into a corner.

Comment: I never construct it per se, I just use the union to know how much memory I need to allocate to be able to fit `T` and a pointer to the next node. I never want to construct the union by itself, just allocate enough memory for it and be able to call the constructor of `T` manually via the placement new when I want to use `T`.

Comment: So you need to fix your code. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union). You either need to follow the pre-C++11 ("Unions cannot contain a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function (copy constructor, copy-assignment operator, or destructor).") or the corresponding C++11 rule. Your code is *broken*.

Comment: The C++11 rule says that in this case it is deleted, and I don't care since I don't want to construct the `MemoryPoolNode`. I will call the constructor of `T` by myself later, so I don't see why this is a problem.

Comment: You probably should consider [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)

Comment: This is exactly why I'm doing, @Basile. I allocate memory with the code shown in my question and then I use the placement new to construct T.

Comment: You do want to construct the `MemoryPoolNode` -- your questions asks for the right way to do that! You also want to construct the `T` yourself later. See my updated answer.

Comment: Your updated answer seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. Yet, I don't see how the result will be different with this approach. Both of them compile and seem to work.

Comment: Do you want code that is guaranteed to work because it follows the requirements of the language? Or do you want code that happens to work by luck on your platform?

Comment: Ok, so this answers my question! Thank you very much! Last question: since my constructors and my destructors are "deleted" from the union, I'm still able to call them manually (via the placement new), right?

Comment: Placement new is `void* ad = ::operator new(sizeof(MemoryPoolNode);` or `void* ad = malloc(sizeof(MemoryPoolNode));` to get some fresh address, then `MemoryPoolNode *node = new(ad) MemoryPoolNode;` to build an object at that address.

Comment: Above you say "and" as in "store both"  I assume you know that each node will store *either*, not both.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't know how to express it. "Or" wouldn't be better I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is broken and you need to fix it first.

Pre-C++11:

> Unions cannot contain a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function (copy constructor, copy-assignment operator, or destructor).

Post-C++11:

> If a union contains a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function (default constructor, copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment, or destructor), that function is deleted by default in the union and needs to be defined explicitly by the programmer.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union). You follow neither rule. You need to fix this.

Once you fix it, you can just use `node = new MemoryPoolNode()` and `delete node;`.

For C++11, this will do:

```
union MemoryPoolNode
{
    MemoryPoolNode *next;
    T data;

    MemoryPoolNode() : next(NULL) { ; }
    ~MemoryPoolNode() { ; }
};
```